# How to avoid multiple mongo db connections in spark scala

Tags: database, mongodb, scala, apache-spark, connection

MapPartitions is leading to too many connections and foreachPartitions doesn’t return anything. Is there any other go ?

Answer (score 0):

It’s worked fine with map partitions when I did coalesce (20) , it created 20 connections.